# Uneven dashing in 2D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, export

I am plotting an expression using the `Dashed` directive, but the dashing appears as unevenly spaced.

Here is the code:

```
ratioA[q_, s_] = (2 s + Sin[2 q] - Sin[2 (q - s)])/(2 s + Sin[2 s])

ratioB[q_, s_] = (2 ArcTan[Cot[q/2]] - 
    2 ArcTan[s + Cot[q/2]] + (-2 + Cos[q]) Cot[
      q/2] + (s + Cot[q/2]) (1 + 2/(1 + (s + Cot[q/2])^2)))/s

Plot[{ratioA[q, 1], ratioB[q, 1]}, {q, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Darker[Blue], {Dashed, Red}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {0, 2}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Table[k, {k, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/2}], 
    None}}]
```

It produces the following picture:

[image]

The problem is evident around `Pi`.

Can anybody suggest a way to solve this?

Comment: You can try passing arguments to `Dashing` or using `Dotted`

Comment: @b3m2a1 I have tried both. Same behavior occurs.

Comment: Try `Exclusions -> None`

Comment: @yarchik Yes, that solves my problem, thanks!